# What is the fastest way to marshal data out of JNI

Tags: java, android-ndk, java-native-interface

Suppose that I have a C data-structure containing many data fields (>15):

```
struct MyData
{
   int x;
   float y;
   ...
}
```

In Java, I can store a pointer to a MyData as a long, and access members of the C data structure through JNI calls:

```
long mydata_p = MyDataJNI.alloc();

int x = MyDataJNI.getX( mydata_p );
float y = MyDataJNI.getY( mydata_p );
...
```

However, the calls to these functions are shockingly expensive (10x-100x the cost of an equivalent C function call). This is true even if the implementation getX, getY, ... is as simple as:

```
return ((MyData*)())->x
```

Q1: Why are JNI calls so expensive? What else is going on other than a call to a function pointer? (For reference, I'm looking at JNI calls in Android.)

Q2: What is the fastest what to make all of the elements of my C structure available at the Java layer?

Comment: Is there a compelling reason to use JNI rather than just loading the C structs into native Java objects?

Comment: The C struct is the result of a lot of computation by a C library. Is there another way to fill the Java object from C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to move all of the data with a single JNI call.  You can either copy it into a primitive byte array (and then extract Java primitives from that using some combination of ByteArrayOutputStream and DataOutputStream), or use a direct NIO ByteBuffer (ByteBuffer.allocateDirect), which makes more sense if you need to move data back and forth.  The direct ByteBuffer is specifically designed and optimized for sharing memory between the VM and native code.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of storing the results of the native call in an externally managed pointer, you could have it return the result in a Java object.

The easiest would be to memcpy the C structs straight into a `byte[]`, and then on the Java side, wrap that array in a `ByteBuffer` and read it with `getInt()`, `getFloat()`, etc.

You could also return an array of Java objects constructed to reflect your structs, but the code would be an unbelievable mess, somewhat akin to constructing everything through reflection with explicit memory management.